Using AI-generated illustrations in my open source app
Our open source app is rather popular but looks very bland, with some colors but only stock icons and no illustrations.
None of the developers in our community has drawing skills nor vast amounts of time or money, so I have experimented with using Generative AI tools to generate in the same theme various drawings and icons specific to each activity. It is a positive result: it makes the app look much friendlier, as well as giving it a kind of personality.
However, I am not sure how the larger open source community would react if I pushed this to production tomorrow.
Question: Are there examples of open source projects openly containing illustrations/icons sourced from Generative AI? How have they been received so far? Do some AI tools generate explicitly open source-friendly (for instance public domain) images?
In the case of AI-generated code being released as open source, I think nobody would bat an eye (EDIT: though even this is debatable judging from the first comment below), but I feel like it could be different for images.

"In the case of AI-generated code being released as open source, I think nobody would bat an eye", I know it's not really your question, but this is highly debatable. If some generated code is "clearly" derivative of some other codebase, programmers would likely bat more than several eyeballs, depending on how the supposedly "license-free" AI-generated code is used. In theory, machine-generated output is uncopyrightable. But we all have seen AI output that is way too close to the training data to know that this is 100% true. Yet, I don't think there have been any legal rulings on this yet.

@Brandin this is misinformation. Yes in theory it’s possible for an LLM to generate a verbatim copy of someone’s code in infringement of their license. In practice that’s not how the LLM architectures work and none of the frontier models ever generate more than a trivial amount of existing code. Such statements made some sense two years ago when this stuff was brand new but by now there’s full consensus that all LLM generate code is public domain and not infringing on copyright.

There is no such global consensus, and in some jurisdictions that last sentence is definitively and completely wrong. See, eg, this summary of the UK legal position for more information.

@MadHatter OK, I think I've found the perfect solution for OP: open source icons. See my updated answer below.

There are a number of different aspects you probably have to consider here.
Are generative AI outputs a derivative work of their inputs?
As of 2024, this an open question. If the outputs are derivative works of their inputs, the images generated by the vast majority of generative AI models are copyright violations as they've been trained by scraping the web.
There are potentially some exceptions here, for example Adobe Firefly which has been trained only on images licensed by Adobe and public domain images (but see next point).
Can the creator of a generative AI model claim copyright on the outputs of the model?
Again, an open question. While we have a canonical question on the subject to which the answer would apparently be "no", the argument being made by the model creators is that the generated images are derivative works of the model and therefore they can claim copyright.
As far as I'm aware, the creators of every major generative AI image generation model make some kind of claim on the output which would in our terms make the output non-free. That includes Adobe Firefly, for which the T&Cs prevent you using the output to train your own AI model.
What does the open source community think about generative AI?
I think the only safe thing to say here is that opinion is mixed. You can be pretty sure that somebody will be upset if you use generative AI assets in your open source project; other people may be supportive.

The copyright status of both the images and the models is very much up in the air. One or both of them might be public domain due to failing to meet the threshold of originality (but this is still an open question, so they might also be copyrighted). If they are public domain, then those terms and conditions can at most bind the person who agrees to them, and not the whole world. To be clear: The model's architecture and hyperparamaters are more likely to enjoy copyright protection, less so the weights learned by training.

@JonathanReez we both know we disagree on this. If you think it's important, you can write your own answer.

Consider using open-source icons instead
Before we get into the complex debacle of incorporating GenAI into OSS, perhaps there is a third path you haven't considered? You mention that your goal is to incorporate new icons into the app:

I have experimented with using Generative AI tools to generate various drawings and icons specific to each activity in the same theme. It is a positive result: it makes the app look much friendlier, as well as giving it a kind of personality.

Instead of using the GenAI outputs directly, you could use them as inspiration for picking the most fitting icons from one of the numerous human-designed, openly licensed projects. One example is Figma-sponsored Glyphs.fyi which has 860 icons provided under the MIT license. GitHub has numerous similar projects to choose from, so I'm relatively confident you could find a close-enough match without any licensing issues.

Sample icons from Glyphs by Goran Spasojevic, MIT license
Opinion of the OSS community

However, I am not sure how the larger open source community would react if I pushed this to production tomorrow.

Wikipedia is the largest open source community in the world when it comes to freely licensed images and has strict guidelines on what can be uploaded to their site. Their current official policy is that AI-generated art/images are perfectly acceptable to be used under a free license, with some minor caveats.
This also applies internationally: Czech Wiki has stricter rules and doesn't allow fair use images in their articles to ensure compliance with Czech copyright law. But they have no problem with AI artwork and currently allow it to be used freely.

Are there examples of open source projects openly containing illustrations/icons sourced from Generative AI?

Sure, here are a few examples I could find:

https://github.com/namidaco/namida (2.3k stars, Midjourney logo)
https://github.com/openbao/openbao/issues/150 (3k stars, link discussed replacing one AI logo with another, nobody bats an eye)
https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv/discussions/1843 (2.5k stars, discusses new AI logo, nobody objects)
https://github.com/fe1ixxu/ALMA/commit/8cb608ffea05c5add0744ac2dab2eb07f64f780d (435 stars, Midjourney logo)

Ask your community for their opinion, not the OSS community in general
Even if Wiki says it's OK and other GitHub projects have been able to include GenAI images, your own community might be opposed to the idea. Treat this change as any other: start a new pull request showcasing the proposed AI artwork and ask people for feedback. Do they like the new icons? Are they personally opposed to GenAI or LLMs? Perhaps someone in your community will volunteer to create human-generated icons instead? If you have an email list, you can also ask the question there. See what your most active contributors and users have to say about it.
What about copyright law?
As correctly pointed out in the other answers, there is a chance that OpenAI, Midjourney, Meta, and others will end up losing in court and AI-generated images will be declared in violation of copyright law, at least in certain jurisdictions. Even if they do prevail in court, it's possible that some countries will change their laws to restrict GenAI output in some way. Even if this happens, the realistic worst-case scenario is that you'll end up removing the GenAI artwork from your project. The odds of someone taking the time to sue a small open-source project for using a few GenAI icons are absurdly low, so you have no reason to worry about copyright.
Set yourself a reminder for 2026 to check on the latest developments in AI copyright law: if things change, delete the icons from the repository and you'll be in the clear.
What if I accidentally generate art that closely resembles a copyrighted work?
There is always a tiny chance that the AI will end up generating an output that's extremely close in resemblance to a copyrighted work. But you can fully mitigate this risk by doing a reverse image search in Google Images and TinEye. If you end up finding artwork that closely resembles the generated illustrations, just hit the "generate" button again and use a different output instead.
What about copyright law in other countries?
Wikipedia's guidelines and the World Intellectual Property Organization's 2024 report discuss this question in detail. Some countries (India, Ireland, New Zealand, South Africa, the UK) might grant copyright to the user writing the prompt, but this is not a concern for your use case, as you'll (presumably) be the person generating the images and contributing them to your repository under an open license. And again: the worst-case scenario is that you'll get a DMCA-like request asking you to remove the artwork to comply with the laws of [some country] in the future; the odds of someone immediately jumping to take you to court are too small to worry about.
Are there tools that are explicitly open-source friendly?
Not that I'm aware of, as the vast majority of images out there are copyrighted, so it would be nearly impossible to create a good image generator using only images that are known to be in the public domain or freely licensed. This is quite unlike code, where the vast majority of training data was sourced from open source projects.
If you want to be extra careful, avoid using Midjourney as it requires a license for commercial use by large entities. Wikipedia thinks such terms are unenforceable, but I'd avoid using their model just to be safe. DALL-E and other top-tier image models don't have such restrictions.

+1 Many fantastic paragraphs in your answer, but regarding the first paragraph: I should have been clearer that I am looking for large detailed illustrations representing very specific situations, for instance a perplexed person looking at a map. Such a detailed illustration would take a lot of effort to draw using icon parts. Context: https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues/5799

@NicolasRaoul wow, this being an app for Wikimedia Commons makes my answer a 100% match :-)
